# Filtering on sonarqube Type (i.e. Bug/Vulnerability/Code Smell) = empty results

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

The "Type" filter for my installation of SonarQube 5.6 appears to be non-functional. Note in the first screen-shot that the number of Rules of Type Bug, Vulnerability, or Code Smell is 0 (even though several Rules in the screen shot are of that Type). The second screen shot shows that filtering on one of these Types does indeed lead to an empty set result.

[0 Rules of Type Bug, Vulnerability, or Code Smell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78LuI.png)
[Empty set results when filtering on Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD0xX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those search facets are populated from ElasticSearch. The fact that they're screwed up indicates that the ES indices are toast. Try deleting */data/es* and restarting.

Comment: That seems to have been the issue. I deleted the /opt/sonar/data/es directory, restarted the server, and all is now well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Darrin if my answer was indeed helpful, you might accept it. It gives me a rep award and indicates quickly to others that it worked for you (not everyone will read the comments. But they'll see the green checkmark.